# Kafka topic is getting reappeared after 10 sec of deletion

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm facing issue with kafka topic deletion.

Using kafka rest API's to create/delete topic and for producing & consuming messages. I have tried to delete the topic where the topic will be deleted, but after some time say 10 sec, topic gets reappeared.

Have checked the Consumer Group offsets and LAG is listed as negative.

docker run   --net=host   --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.1.0   kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:2181  --describe --group grp1

GROUP    TOPIC  PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG    OWNER

grp1   topic1      0        3              0             **-3**     none

Answer (score 3):

It seems deleting a kafka topic is still has some bugs.

*** The only way to delete a topic permanently is as follows: ***

- stop the brokers
- remove the directories on disk

`sudo rm -rf kafka_data_dir/topic_name`

- remove the topic from zookeeper:

`bin/zkCli.sh` - to start zookeeper shell

`rmr /config/topics/topic_name`

`rmr /brokers/topics/topic_name`

`rmr /admin/delete_topics/topic_name`

Comment: Thanks @Subhranshu. Are there any known open issues for this bug which can be referred ?

Comment: What version of kafka are you using?

Comment: This still seems to be a problem in 2.2. I can't ever seem to delete topics in Kafka without them reappearing a minute or two later.

Answer (score 3):

You might have enabled the `auto.create.topics.enable` property which automatically creates a topic if any Producer [or] Consumer issues a request to Kafka broker with send / subscribe / assign request.

Once you have deleted the topic, either Consumer / Producer issued a request to the broker which in-turn created a new topic (with the same name).

You can disable the property(default: true) and re-test your setup. Use `AdminUtils` to create the topic. Topic deletion is much improved in the latest version of Kafka.

Comment: Have not enabled the auto.create.topics.enable property , only delete topic is enabled in properties. I'm bringing up the zookeper/kafka as a docker container. Can you specify which files/functions are fixed/improved in the latest version of Kafka ?